# Original form of this sentence : Our collection spans musical genres from rock and roll to opera, highlighting England's great artistic contributors

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns, omissibility

I think there is relative pronouns omitted in this sentence.

"Our collection spans musical genres from rock and roll to opera, highlighting England's great artistic contributors."

And What I want to know is original form of this sentence.
(ex. Our collection spans musical genres from rock and roll to opera,**[which is]** highlighting England's great artistic contributors.) -> just my opinion.

And what "which" refers to.
(ex. In above the sentence, "which" indicates "Our collection" or "musical genres")

I'm not good in English. so if you can't understand my question, I will try to revise it.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's a perfectly good sentence without any relative pronoun. And the phrase *highlighting England's...* modifies the entire independent clause.

Comment: The paraphrase may be either "Our collection spans musical genres from rock and roll to opera, and in doing so highlights England's great artistic contributors." or "Our collection spans musical genres from rock and roll to opera, and highlights England's great artistic contributors."

Comment: Now I understand that sentence. Both you explain my question quite well. So thanks.